# Strange OpenGL Pixel Imperfections

Tags: opengl

A very small percentage (<1%) of my users are experiencing a strange distortion with the OpenGL UI of my game. It would appear that my pixel-perfect projection setup:

```
glViewport(0, 0, clientSizeWidth, clientSizeHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, clientSizeWidth, clientSizeHeight, 0, -1.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
double transAmount = 0.375;
glTranslated(transAmount, transAmount, 0.0);
```

Is causing issues on their systems. And I've been unsuccessful in gathering details about their systems, but I believe they can run similar OpenGL games with success. So I believe my code is at fault.

Here is a picture of visual artifacts:

[image: visual artifacts]

And here is a picture without visual artifacts (*ignore the difference in OS*):

[image: without visual artifacts]

Although my game scales the final render to be 2x, it does so via a single call to `glSubTexImage2D` after the 1x render has been performed. This means the artifacts in the first screenshot were present prior to the pixel doubling (hence why the artifacts are also pixel doubled). So the pixel doubling itself couldn't be the source of issue.

Any thoughts on what could cause this? I presently have no way to test. The overwhelming majority of users (myself included) experience no visual artifacts.

**Edit (April 30th)**: A Polish user has informed me his/her videocard experiences these artifacts and is a "nVidia 9500 GS". Not sure if this means [9500M GS](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-9500m-gs) or [9500 GT](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9500-gt), but both seem fairly modern.

Comment: Where does `0.375` come from?

Comment: @BenVoigt It's from the OpenGL Redbook. See [this](http://glprogramming.com/red/appendixg.html#name1) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537007%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The fact that it 1) happens only on some surfaces 2) happens at different scales for different surfaces should be a big hint as to where the problem code will be.

Comment: @Patashu There's only one surface (the window surface).

Comment: @Mr. Smith I might be using the wrong word, what I mean is the stone-texture background and the main view have the graphical error at different scales, so it happened once for the background AND for the main view, e.g. for some piece of code they both commonly use (and that, say, the map does not? Hmm)

Comment: @Patashu Artifacts appear on the edges of quads; stone is roughly `40x40` `px` quads, view is `16x16`. Map is special (`glSubTexImage2D ` involved). Quad rendering code a copy&paste from OpenGL Redbook; works great, except for few people. My hunch, bad OpenGL drivers; they only need `OpenGL 1.2` version, so potentially very old cards. I hope to learn of a workaround.

Comment: It seems like you're using GL_LINEAR when scaling, which distorts the artifacts. Are you using GL_NEAREST for the initial rendering? Could you post the texturing part of your code? It looks like the texture sampler uses colors from the neighboring textures in your texture atlas. If I wanted to produce this effect voluntarily, the first thing I would try is to offset the texture coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's 90% probability, that user experiencing this problem has texture quality switch in their nVidia control panel on some non-default value. in your case, GL_NEAREST should help to avoid such issues(so it won't average neighbour texels for upscaled images). but first, ask him to set nVidia control panel settings to default to prove or break the theory.

Comment: ty ty ty ty! The particular nVidia override seems to be `Antialiasing - Mode`, I tested it and got similar pixel imperfections. Case solved!